# NSColor. Can I write this little piece of code in one line?

Tags: objective-c, nscolor

Can I declare and initialise the colour inside the message to myLabel? Or this the only way to do it? Sorry if this is to simple for you guys.

```
- (IBAction)changeLabel:(id)sender {

NSColor *green = [NSColor greenColor];
[myLabel setTextColor:green];
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can :)

```
- (IBAction)changeLabel:(id)sender {
     [myLabel setTextColor:[NSColor greenColor]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! one more thing. Does it works like that because its a Class method?

Comment: @ToTCaMbIu: It works that way because `[NSColor greenColor]` returns an NSColor object that can be passed directly to the `setTextColor` method.

Comment: It make no difference if it is a class method or instance. Just don't lose clarity by making lines to long and/r confusing.